# Rego based OPA Policy for restricting Argo CD applications being created in default Argo CD project is not working with Gatekeeper

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, opa, rego

Rego based OPA Policy for restricting Argo CD applications being created in default Argo CD project is not working with Gatekeeper. I have tried multiple combinations of api versions and kinds in the constraint as well. Constraint template and constraint gets applied successfully but the creation of Argo Application still goes through successfully without being restricted which was expected.

Gatekeeper version: 3.8.1
Kubernetes version: 1.22.9

**ConstraintTemplate**

```
apiVersion: templates.gatekeeper.sh/v1
kind: ConstraintTemplate
metadata:
  name: k8snoappindefaultargoproject
  annotations:
    description: >-
      Restricts any ArgoCD Applications to be created in default ArgoCD project
spec:
  crd:
    spec:
      names:
        kind: K8sNoAppInDefaultArgoProject
  targets:
    - target: admission.k8s.gatekeeper.sh
      rego: |
        package k8snoappindefaultargoproject
        violation[{"msg": def_msg}] {
          name := input.review.object.metadata.name
          mySpec := input.review.object.spec
          mySpec.project == "default"
          def_msg := sprintf("Error: `%v` ArgoCD Application is not permitted to use default ArgoCD project.",[name])
        }
```

**Constraint**

```
apiVersion: constraints.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1
kind: K8sNoAppInDefaultArgoProject
metadata:
  name: no-app-in-default-argo-project
spec:
  enforcementAction: deny
  match:
    kinds:
      - apiGroups: ["argoproj.io/v1alpha1"]
        kinds: ["Application"]
```

**Update:**

We were able to resolve this by refactoring the rego code as below. Maybe that's how rego works that we need to assign the extracted value to a variable before comparing.

```
          name := input.review.object.metadata.name
          mySpec := input.review.object.spec
>         myProject := mySpec.project
>         myProject == "default"
          def_msg := sprintf("Error: `%v` ArgoCD Application is not permitted to use default ArgoCD project.",[name])
```